# Counting number of program using shared library

Tags: c++, linux, static, global

I have a library foo.so. Each time a new program starts it loads using this library. 
I want to declare (somehow) a static variable in library and ask through one program bar which was also loaded using foo.so library, how many programs were loaded (using this  library). I tried static and extern but every time the variable is initialized to zero for each each program, (so that when I ask bar about counter it tells me its 1). Is is possible to somehow get the result I wanted?

Comment: You should store the counter in a file because your library variables may disappear when the library is not in use (and the OS kills it).

Comment: That means opening writing closing for every entry to be written and
opening reading closing every time I need to read. That's a lot of I/O for such a small task.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use some sort of cross-process construct. I'm out of practice on linux, but I suspect [shared memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) or a [semaphore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) would be a decent choice. Since you wouldn't be using a semaphore for it's normal purpose, it may look a little weird, or might even stop working. But I think a simple semaphore approach would be to do the following:

**On load:** [`sem_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html) to create your semaphore with a unique name and a count of 0, or open an already created semaphore. Then [`sem_post`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_post.3.html) to increment its value.

**On check:** [`sem_getvalue`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_getvalue.3.html) to read the current count stored in the semaphore.

**On unload:** [`sem_wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html) (or one of its try or timeout variants) to decrement the semaphore's count followed by [`sem_close`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_close.3.html) if you're cleaning up resources carefully. If you're feeling nice and can avoid the race condition, call [`sem_unlink`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_unlink.3.html) or [`sem_destroy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_destroy.3.html) to release system resources once they're all unloaded.

(Optionally you could try to open, process, and close the semaphore in each of these places in order to avoid having to pass around the `sem_t`. But if the system automatically cleans up a semaphore that is not open anywhere, this would be disastrous for your purposes.)

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but imagine, the requirement changes and I need to store the names of programs as well. I would be using some sort of list for that(let's say MAXSIZE 100 entries, 1 entry = 128 Bytes). And keeping that much shared memory reserved would not be such a good idea.

Comment: I think I could do by passing the information when every programs loads to an other program, but for that too I have to be sure this program is the first one to be started so not to miss any entry. But still this program will require extra memory and CPU, so still far from ideal.

Comment: @user1566277 Sure, a change in requirements will likely yield a change in optimal implementation (not that shm/sem was optimal to start with). You might also look into searching `/proc` or similar, but unless there's a snapshot version you might hit some interesting data races.